# Поиск по определенным полям в структуре

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте. У меня есть две матрицы. Размер структуры `closed_list` `1x3`. Размер структуры `current.NEIB` -- `1x1`. Они имеют 2 одинаковых поля (координаты x и y). Необходимо определить присутствие координат `current.NEIB` в `closed_list`.

Например:

```
clc; clear all;
closed_list(1).currX=1;
closed_list(1).currY=1;
closed_list(1).obj=0;
closed_list(2).currX=2;
closed_list(2).currY=2;
closed_list(2).obj=1;
closed_list(3).currX=3;
closed_list(3).currY=3;
closed_list(3).obj=0;

current.NEIB(1).currX=1;
current.NEIB(1).currY=0;

for v=1:size(current.NEIB,2)                                                                                                                  
    for c=1:size(closed_list,2)                                                                                                               
            if (current.NEIB(v).currX==closed_list(c).currX || current.NEIB(v).currY==closed_list(c).currY)
            disp('Присутствует'); 
            end                                                                                                                               
    end                                                                                                                                       
end
```

в этом примере он все равно указывает на присутствие (1;0) среди координат:

```
>>Присутствует
```

Как можно исправить эти циклы?

Comment: Обратите внимание на правки. Вы не понимаете, что такое структуры и матрицы. Я думаю, что Ваш код не работает.

Comment: Я добавил конкретики, что же тогда `1x3 struct`, если не структура 1х3?

Comment: Вероятно, это массив. Но не структура.

Comment: Вообще, в матлабе циклы использовать -- это плохо

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас, к сожалению, под рукой матлаба нет. Но Вы можете попробовать следующее:

```
ans = (structureB == structureA)
```

Возможно, что такая операция вернёт нужный Вам ответ. В ином случае она закончится ошибкой. В качестве ответа будет возвращён список номеров `structureB`.

Если же данная операция не сработает, то можно сделать так:

```
ans = [];
for i = 1 : 6
    if structureB(i) == structureA(1)
        ans(end + 1) = i
    end
end
ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел сам ошибку, извините за беспокойство!

```
for v=1:size(closed_list,2)
    for c=1:size(current.NEIB,2)                                                                                                               
            if (closed_list(v).currX==current.NEIB(c).currX && closed_list(v).currY==current.NEIB(c).currY)
            disp('Присутствует'); 
            end                                                                                                                               
    end                                                                                                                                       
end
```